# What would be the impact of slighty higher mass for the $W$ boson?

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, standard-model, beyond-the-standard-model, large-hadron-collider

With the recent announcement from CDF

https://cerncourier.com/a/cdf-sets-w-mass-against-the-standard-model/

placing it at the mass at $$80,433.5 \pm 6.4\; \text{(stat)} \pm 6.9\; \text{(syst) MeV},$$ many checks and questions are to be conducted.

Assuming that this measurement does not suffer from systematic errors, pointing at a slightly higher $W$ boson mass, do some models, prior to this announcement, that point towards a higher mass of the W boson, in the context of beyond the standard model revive? In the sense, has the community ruled out certain features or models due to the $W$ boson mass?

Comment: On the experimental cautionary aspects of the measurement: https://non-trivial-solution.blogspot.com/2022/04/do-we-have-finally-found-new-physics.html.

Comment: in general new results even of high statistical significance wait for a confirmation from other experiments . It is the reason why there are very similar very expensive experiments in the same accelerators , (LEP had four, LHC two). to exclude unknown systematic errors

Comment: Paper in [Science](https://www.science.org/doi/10.1126/science.abk1781) instead of PRL. What have you learned about this practice in the past?