# Does the theoretical prediction of the $W$ boson mass rely on the mass of the $Z$ boson?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, standard-model, electroweak

Regarding the recent problem of discrepancy between theoretical and experimental value of $W$ boson mass: I do remember that standard model gives only a relation between $W$ and $Z$ mass and not a prediction of the values themselves. Given that, how is the theoretical prediction formed? Does it take into account the measured value of the $Z$ mass, or what else?

Comment: see comments to this closed question https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/702890/what-are-the-thoughts-on-the-newly-announced-mass-measurement-of-the-w-boson . the link in the question https://cerncourier.com/a/cdf-sets-w-mass-against-the-standard-model/ describes the theoretical calculation,

Comment: @annaV I don't see a description of the theoretical calculation in the linked article. A 2018 paper with a global electroweak fit is along the lines of the theoretical calculation if not the exact one that was used by Fermilab in this paper. https://link.springer.com/article/10.1140/epjc/s10052-018-6131-3

Comment: The paper references the 2020 Particle Data Group value. See Footnote 10. https://www.science.org/doi/10.1126/science.abk1781 The reference is vague but probably to Review paper number 10 "Electroweak Model and Constraints on New Physics"

Comment: The cited 2020 PDG value does not match the number in the 2020 W boson mass paper however. https://pdg.lbl.gov/rpp-archive/index-2021.html which is 80,354 ± 7 MeV. While I'm sure that the number isn't made up and I've seen it elsewhere, the citation of their source for it is erroneous.

Comment: from the beginning : "the W mass is a clear prediction of the Standard Model (SM). At lowest order in electroweak theory, it depends solely on the mass of the Z boson and the value of the weak mixing angle."

Comment: The weak mixing angle is, in turn, at lowest order, a function of the electromagnetic and weak force coupling constants.  The Higgs vacuum expectation value, meanwhile, is basically a function of the weak force coupling constant. But, the calculation includes many higher order factors in electroweak theory including the Higgs boson mass and the top quark mass.