# How preciece was the CDF II measuremnet?

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics

I encountered an article ["High-precision measurement of the W boson mass with the CDF II detector"](https://www.science.org/doi/10.1126/science.abk1781) but I didn't quite understand their result. For example, looking at Fig. 5, there was already "D0 1" and "ALEPH" a little bit deviate from the SM calculation, and some experiments did not agree with respect to their standard deviations.

Is CDF II experiment a concrete conclusion("precise enough" from the experimental point of the view), or a further indicator?

Comment: see comments on a similar question here https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/703243/

Comment: @annav so from your comment in https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/702890/   It's an indicator required more experiments? and the result was yet to be taken seriously? (They did have a relatively high difference with respect to the standard deviation. I was thinking about the Chebyshev’s theorem and it looked impressive. But the history kicked in and said be cautious.)

Comment: not only my comments.  yes, more experiments are needed for checks for any new phenomenon to exclude unexpected systematic errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just sat through a zoom  lecture by John Ellis reviewing the theoretical models for this measurement. I think he said there are over 90 theory papers proposing various higher level solutions.

I still would press for a second, independent, experiment from  CDF to avoid systematic errors unknown at present, no matter how good their analysis may look.Also a real effort should be made to understand  mathematically why all the other independent experiments gather over a [significantly different value :](https://cerncourier.com/a/cdf-sets-w-mass-against-the-standard-model/)

[image: w mass]

They must all be falling to the same error to  have such a discrepancy .

I remember when working in ALEPH we had announced a Higgs discovery at 114 GeV. which became statistically insignificant when the other three LEP experiments came in with their data.